# Tax Free when leaving EU through a different country

Tags: italy, netherlands, eu, ams, tax-refunds

I bought the laptop in Netherlands but am planning to leave EU through Italy.

How can I get tax refunds in my case?

Do I need to stamp my receipts in both: Schiphol and Milano airports?

Comment: Is it worth it? In our old laws (do not know nowadays), the paperwork meant I had to pay VAT on my side, which meant usually ending up paying more, especially in electronic goods.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro as I know it depends on your  country of residence. In my country it does worth it)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Actually I found the answer, in case someone else wonder if it's possible, the answer was found [here](https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/individuals/travelling/travellers-leaving-eu/guide-vat-refund-visitors-eu_en).

> Do I have to leave the EU straight away from the country where I
>   purchased goods? No. You can buy VAT-free goods even if you are going
>   to be visiting other EU countries before you finally return home, as
>   long as you actually leave the EU with the goods within the time
>   limit. You have to get your documents stamped by a customs officer at
>   the point of exit of the EU – not necessary in the same EU country
>   where you bought it.
>
> Be careful if you leave the EU by train! You may be able to get the
>   VAT refund documents stamped at certain train stations of the
>   departure. However, you might as well need to get off the train at the
>   last station within the EU to get this stamp. Other methods could also
>   apply (e.g. a customs officer might be boarding the train) .
>
> This depends on the trains’ route and the internal arrangements in
>   each EU country.
>
> We therefore strongly advise you to consult in advance the national
>   authorities or your refund company on the arrangements applicable in
>   our concrete route.

Comment: One quick tip here. Even though Switzerland is part of Schengen, it is not a part of the EU customs union. If you happen to buy your tax-free goods in the Netherlands, fly to Zurich, and then fly to the USA, a very nice customs officer in Zurich will tell you that he cannot stamp your paperwork. Ask me how I know.